# Recreating .NET rounding behavior in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to migrate a subtle calculation from C#.NET to TSQL and absolutely every result must remain the same, regardless of whether the original C#.NET answer is inaccurate in some cases.

My TSQL script mostly succeeds at this, however, there is some unusual rounding behavior in .NET that I've been unable to capture. I'll demonstrate with two examples:

Here's the .NET code that I'm trying to recreate.

```
(double)Math.Round(number, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero );

double number = 6.1499999999999995; // returns 6.1
double number = 6.9499999999999993;  // returns 7  (which, to me, seems inconsistent)
```

Here's the TSQL code that I'm trying to align with the .NET code above.

```
SELECT ROUND(ROUND(CAST(@Score as decimal(10,1)), 16), 1)

DECLARE @Score DECIMAL(18,16) = 6.1499999999999995 -- returns 6.1
DECLARE @Score DECIMAL(18,16) = 6.9499999999999993 -- returns 6.9 (needs to be 7)
```

My goal is to get my TSQL code to return 7 instead of 6.9 in the second case. Does anyone know how I can make that happen?

Comment: it's because doubles in C# are floating point, and some decimal numbers cannot be represented accurately in binary. If you need precision and accuracy, use the `decimal` type instead in your C# code. Trying to replicate erroneous behaviour is just wrong.

Comment: Did you know you can call .NET functions from SQL Server? This is called [CLR user defined function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) If this is really that big of an issue you can use your existing function. (however, keep in mind the .NET version is giving the wrong answer)

Comment: CLR is not in option in this case. We're actually migrating this calculation to SQL in order to avoid CLR altogether to abide by a security restriction.

Comment: You know that .NET returns a wrong result (due to floating point arithmetic) and want TSQL to return the same wrong result?

Comment: I am absolutely aware of this. The .NET style calculation comes from a major standards agency and I do not have the option of changing their code. I simply need to recreate it, inaccuracies and all

Comment: Wrong standards, nice :)

Comment: @dnoeth Depends on the requirements entirely. If you're looking for compatibility, `7` is the correct result, and that's it. If you're looking for decimal precision, you should know how *much* decimal precision - the real problem isn't floating point precision per-se, but rather the precision mismatch - there's no way a `double` is going to give you 18 digits of precision, floating arithmetic or not.

Comment: @Luaan:That's why you shouldn''t use DOUBLE when you need 18 digits, most DBMSes support at least 38 digits.

Answer (score 3):

`decimal` is a decimal-accurate number. `double` isn't. Since your C# code is using `double`, only real way to replicate a similar behaviour in T-SQL is to also use a binary floating point number in T-SQL - `float` (specifically, `double` corresponds to `float(53)`). The rounding behaviour isn't "unusual", it follows the IEEE-754 standard.

However, if you care about decimal precision (as it seems you should), you should really push switching the C# code to use `decimal` instead of `double`. Binary floating points are a terrible choice when you want decimal precision.

Comment: I tried switching to the real datatype, however, it returned 6.2 instead of 6.1 for the first testcase. Here's my code `DECLARE @EnvironmentalScore2 real = 6.1499999999999995;   
SELECT ROUND(ROUND(CAST(@EnvironmentalScore2 as real), 16), 1)`

Comment: @fyodorfranz Duh, my bad. `float(53)` is the `double` equivalent :) `real` is `float(24)`, the largest 4-byte precision.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, while float(53) get's 6.1  for the second test case, it gets 6.9 for the first test case (when I need 7). Here's my code: `DECLARE @Score float(53) = 6.9499999999999993
SELECT ROUND(ROUND(CAST(@Score as float(53)), 16), 1)`

Comment: @fyodorfranz Well, that just means T-SQL always uses an estimate, rather than doing floating point rounding, even on floating point numbers (which is kind of a good thing, since the exact rounding implementation is platform-specific). However, the fundamental problem is still that you're expecting 17 decimal digits of precision from a `double`, which simply isn't possible - you only get 15.95 decimal digits. If you remove one (ideally, two) of the nines, you'll get correct results for both C# and T-SQL. Why are you trying to handle numbers that don't fit the data format?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there a reliable way to get what you want using plain T-SQL.

Your logic is wrong:

`CAST(@Score as decimal(10,1))` already rounds before you apply ROUND

```
DECLARE @Score decimal(18,16) = 6.9499999999999993

SELECT @Score, CAST(@Score as decimal(10,1))

6.9499999999999993 6.9
```

And you `ROUND` to 16 digits and then apply another `ROUND` to 1 digit, but `ROUND(ROUND(n, 16), 1)` might be a different result than `ROUND(@n,1)` directly and is definitely not the way .NET rounds.

Another problem is the rounding rule, you specify `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`, but afaik the default for T-SQL is [Rounding to Even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even).

You might check [SQL Server Rounding Methods](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-rounding-methods/) and try to implement *Round to Even* but then there's still the problem of significant digits, `DEC(18,16)` has 18, but `DOUBLE` only 16.

If you can't use a CLR-function in T-SQL or switch to `DECIMAL` in .NET you're probably doomed...

Comment: Thanks for this. As a last ditch effort, I was thinking of handling these kind of cases with some elaborate switch statements, checking the values at certain relevant decimal places, and deciding from that, whether to round up or down. Do you know what about the C# code makes it the case that the first number rounds down to 6.1 but the second number rounds up to 7?

Comment: @fyodorfranz: I don't know about C#, maybe changing the rounding rule to `MidpointRounding.ToEven` helps, but you still got the precision problem. Can't you switch to DECIMAL in C#?

Comment: I can't switch to decimal in C#. The decision to do the calculation in this way was made by a standards agency that I have no connection to. My job is to recreate their apparently imprecise method of executing this calculation in TSQL without using any CLRs.

Comment: @fyodorfranz: If you switch to FLOAT in TSQL it might be easier to mimic. It's probably hard to argue with people claimimg "*we define the standard and you have to follow*". Btw, *In theory, there is no difference between theory and practice. But, in practice, there is* :-)

Comment: No, T-SQL is rounding midpoint away-from-zero, and that's the only mode it knows how do to.